# telegram bot, callback query of an inline button in a group chat, redirect the user to private chat of bot. python

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My bot sends messages to groups with inline button, what I want, is when the button is clicked, chat with the bot page should open, i.e. somehow redirect the user to the private chat with the bot.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) wrapper.

What I have tried so far is to set a url in **answer_callback** method, equal to the url of my bot i.e. url="https://t.me/my_sample_bot
but I keep getting URL_INVALID response from telegram, I tried http(since I read somewhere in the api documentation that the urls should be HTTP), but that did not work either.

My question is am I doing it right? I mean do I have to set the url in answer_callback method to redirect the user, or I should try another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself, setting the url was the right way to do it, and though the Wrappers documentation is not detailed, I took a look at source code and there was a docstring for the method **answer_callback_query** that said this about the url:

> :param url: (Optional) URL that will be opened by the user's client. If you have created a Game and accepted the conditions via @Botfather, specify the URL that opens your game – note that this will only work if the query comes from a callback_game button.
>       Otherwise, you may use links like telegram.me/your_bot?start=XXXX that open your bot with a parameter.

so all I had to do was to give it a link with of my bot, with a start query

Comment: and what do i put in callback_query_id?

Comment: How can I have the same effect, but instead of using buttons, use commands?

Comment: @Retr0 anything unique should work for the callback_query_id. You have to have a definition for each of your callbacks. I'm not sure about the commands however. about the commands, have you checked out available methods in the bot documentation? methods like `bot.getChat`. you can see them [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L540)